# Can I add some words into the idiom "last but not least"?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

The phrase 'last but not least' is a well-established one, but I'm wondering whether I can split it and add a parenthetical bit into it:

> And finally, the last but definitely not the least geocache I have found on the island, was this one.

Does it make sense, or does it sound weird/wrong?

Comment: I'd be interested to know how you qualify a geocache. It seems to be a strange idiom to use in this context. The usual meaning is that the 'last' may be inferior, but for a geocache may have been the most difficult.

Comment: It does sound weird to me. The idiom is usually used to show that there is no merit inherent in the order of a list or sequence. "The final, and perhaps the most challenging geocache I found was this one." Note 'found' and not 'have found' – it was the last one, so there should be no implication that there is more to come.

Comment: Geocache is basically a treasure, part of some outdoor game, you find it and log it. I am logging a geocache which I have found on one island as the last one and want to express it was not less important than the ones I have found before.

Comment: The whole sentence is clumsy, using 'finally' and 'last', and adding 'on the island' which readers will already know, since you are describing the last find. If you want to use an idiom safely, then use its usual form. "And last but not least, this geocache ..."

Comment: The main reason to specify *last but not least* is not to insult the last person you list. People can feel snubbed. Geocaches, less so.

Comment: Readers won't know because each cache is logged individually. I wanted to start my log by expressing I value this last cache same as others in the beginning of the log. But thank you guys, I think I understand now better the phrase itself and why I probably need some better intro.

Comment: "last but definitely not the least" sounds OK to me, as it's just intensifying the usual meaning. There are plenty of Google hits for the phrase. The sentence has other problems, as mentioned (punctuation, word order, what the "least" geocache is, what you actually mean).

Comment: As Stuart says, idioms are not totally resistant to modification. But knowing how one can acceptably tinker with them is an art. I find '... the last but definitely not the least of the geocaches I have ...' fine. 'Least' directly before a count noun usage, the adjective meaning slightest/smallest,  is pretty formal, heading for rarefied except in strings like _least bittern_.

Comment: Of course you can. To me, it's more interesting why you might doubt that…